# How to subset a Data frame column wise using column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a **data frame** named **z**.

```
  a = c(1,1,1);
  b = c(2,2,2);
  c = c(3,3,3);
  d = c(4,4,4);
  z = data.frame(a,b,c,d);
```

I want to **remove column c and d from data frame z**.

I tried this code

```
p = subset(z , colnames(z) == c('a' , 'b'))
```

But i am getting this result

```
a   b   c   d
1   2   3   4   
1   2   3   4
```

What changes should i make in this command to remove column **c** and **d** from **z**.

Comment: `z[, c('a', 'b')]`

Comment: Or argument `select`: `subset(z, select = c('a' , 'b'))`. BTW, why the semi-colon at the end of instructions? `R` is not the C language, the semi-colon separates instructions so when youend an instruction line with it, you are in fact separating it from the end, the NULL instruction.

Comment: @ycw updated :-)

Answer (score 22):

We can use the following to specify which columns to select by names.

```
z[, c("a", "b")]
```

This also works.

```
z[c("a", "b")]
```

Or we can use the following to first specify which columns to remove in a vector, and then select the columns not in that vector.

```
cols_remove <- c("c", "d")
z[, !(colnames(z) %in% cols_remove)]
```

Comment: keeps <- c("a, "b")
DF[keeps]

Comment: @Sateesh Your comment is unclear. It is not reproducible. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Sateesh Is this R code?

Comment: @Sateesh You have not responded my question. What is the purpose of your comment? Is your code really working in R?

Comment: yes it works...

Comment: keeps <- c("a, "b")

Comment: df <- df[keeps]

Comment: @Sateesh Thanks for your response. Now I see that you did not properly format your previous comment, and you did not use the same data frame name as the OP.

Comment: @Sateesh I have updated my post based on your comment.