# R studio: how do I subset only columns that match a list?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I feel like this isnt a hard question, but an hour of googling has gotten me no where.

say I have the following DF

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 4 |

I have hundreds of columns though, and I'm only interested in a specific list. Lets say this list includes "Column A" and "Column C"

I want to then filter the dataframe so it only contains these columns

| Column A | Column C |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

How do I do this?

I tried

which(colnames(data) %in% list)

match(list, names(data))

subset(data, names(data) %in% list)

Comment: `data[list]` or `data[unlist(list)]` should do it, depending on if your "list" is actually a `vector` or a `list`. If that works without further complication, this is probably a duplicate question of something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846341/how-to-subset-a-data-frame-column-wise-using-column-names

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
subset(data, select = names(data) %in% list)
```

The argument `select` used to indicating columns to select from a data frame.

Comment: oh my god. yup, that worked. 

turned out the column names of my list all ended in an a or a z, while the column names of the dataframe didn't :) :) :) it's always something so stupid. 

Ty!!!